# Using modulus to answer: "How close to $\pi$ do we need $x$ to be for $x^2$ to be within $10^{−100}$ of $\pi ^2$?"

Tags: continuity

I'm studying the book: "The Princeton companion to mathematics", I'm in the part of fundamentals: continuity. There is an example I don't get:

> How close to $\pi$ do we need $x$ to be for $x^2$ to be within $10^{−100}$ of $\pi ^2$? To answer this, we can use our earlier argument. Let $x = \pi + \delta$ again. Then $$x^2−\pi^2 = 2\delta \pi+\delta^2$$ and **an easy calculation** shows that this has modulus less than $10^{-100}$ if $\delta$ has modulus less than $10^{-101}$. So we will be all right if we take the first $101$ digits of $\pi$ after the decimal point.

I don't get which was the easy calculation. Can someone help me with that?

And, when it says modulus, is it talking about modular arithmetic?

Comment: $\delta< 10^{-101}\implies 2\delta \pi+\delta^2<7\times 10^{-101}+10^{-202}<10^{-100}$.

Comment: "Modulus" here is a synonym for "absolute value".  Nothing to do with modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\delta \pi + \delta^2 < \delta \pi + \delta$ if $\delta < 1$.

We want $2\delta \pi + \delta^2 < \varepsilon$.

So, it is enough that $2\delta \pi + \delta  < \varepsilon$, or $\delta < \frac{\varepsilon}{2\pi + 1}$.

Now, $2\pi + 1 < 10$ and so it is enough that $\delta < \frac{\varepsilon}{10}$.

Putting this all together:
$$
\delta < \frac{\varepsilon}{10} < 1
\implies
x^2−\pi^2
= 2\delta \pi+\delta^2
< 2\delta \pi + \delta
= (2\pi + 1)\delta
< 10 \delta
< \varepsilon
$$

Comment: Do you mean "So, it is enough that $2\delta\pi+\delta\lt\color{#C00}{\epsilon}\dots$"?

Comment: @robjohn, yes, thanks, fixed.